# Webcomic with a human transported to a world of anthropomorphic animals

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

This one is teasing at the edges of my memory, but I can't quite place it. There were actually two webcomics, with one being a sequel to the other (and a flip of the premise). Somehow (I forget if it was actually explained), a human male (maybe named Brad?) gets transported to a world filled with anthropomorphic animals. A male character (I forget what sort of animal) hides him in the house for fear of people being scared of the strange creature. What ensues is basically a sitcom kind of setup of the man interacting with the cast of characters (the fellow sheltering him... who might be married, and their friends) while they try to figure out how they might get him home. Things I remember from the plotlines:

- At one point, Brad gets bit by a werewolf while on a walk, and thereafter, he occasionally transforms into a relatively unintelligent (but non-violent) wolf man (I think there's some joke about how he acts more like a dog in the form, wanting to play fetch)
- One of the things Brad does to earn his keep is cleaning the house, which I think he does cheerfully and pretty well, although I also remember a scene where the joke was that he'd taken all of the fur clogging the drain and had made himself a large hat out of it while singing "Do the hustle!"
- He has a relationship or two among the anthros, although I can't recall if it went anywhere
- I think that he has a (not very convincing) mask to make him look like a dog that he occasionally used when walking outside
- In the sequel comic, an anthro girl (maybe named Violet?) shows up at Brad's house, having gotten transported in a similar manner as he did (which I suppose would mean he did find a way back home in the original comic), and he has to hide her. I think the comic ended abruptly as a result of a dispute with the artist
- There was a brief gag in one of the comics where Brad was staring, horrified, at an anthro rooster chomping down on a drumstick

I would have read this somewhere in the early 2000s I think, and... actually, in the process of writing this out, I think I found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comic in question was *[Fur Will Fly](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/FurWillFly)* by  Brian Daniel, Misty Caldwell and Richard Wyatt (and Cami Woodruff?)

> Fur Will Fly is a Furry comic (now concluded) about a human named Brad who, after getting fired from his job at Tim Hortons, asks God to, quote, "Bring it on." Less than a second later, he is teleported into a government-funded lab in an Alternate Universe where everyone is an anthromorphic animal in one form or another (the author seems to love throwing obscure or seldom-used animals into the mix). After a series of culture shock strips detailing the differences between the two universes the strip quickly settles into a pattern of following Brad through the various travails, romances and sitcom-esque gags of his new life . . . at least before taking a turn for the dramatic. Luckily, this works to the reader's benefit and is done fairly well.

> - **Carnivore Confusion**: Lampshaded in an early strip in which Brad is understandably somewhat disturbed to see an anthropomorphic chicken tucking into some KFC.
> - **Cool Mask**: At one point Natalie fashions Brad a dog persona mask so that he can freely walk in public and interact with non-protagonist members of the society. Not that it stopped him from doing this before...

The sequel series is *[Coming Up Violet](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/ComingUpViolet)*, which did indeed apparently have the artist falling out, was taken down briefly, came back up with a new artist, and now seems largely taken down again (the URL for the comic still comes up, but the comic pages don't). I was wrong in that it involves a second human, a young girl named Dawn, showing up, and Brad and Page trying to help her hide, with Violet being Tammy's daughter who happens to be about Dawn's age.

Found because the phrase "[Carnivore Confusion](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CarnivoreConfusion/Webcomics)" popped into my head while trying to explain the scene with the chicken, and indeed, it was on TV Tropes.